# Make a field or all fields required in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

I have an input field like this:

```
<Form.Field
  name="contactName"
  className=""
  control={Input}
  label="Contact Name"
  placeholder="Contact Name"
  value={this.state.contactName || ''}
  onChange={this.onChange}
/>
```

and I want to make it required so for that it should be add `required` attribute and now looks like this:

```
<Form.Field
  name="contactName"
  className=""
  control={Input}
  label="Contact Name"
  placeholder="Contact Name"
  value={this.state.contactName || ''}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  required
/>
```

I noticed that it also adds a red asterisk near the input's title. The problem is that the user can still click the submit button and they will not know that the entry was not created (they don't check the network to see the call failed).

Is there a way to make it impossible to submit if the required data is not introduced? Also something like a popup/hover saying that it requires data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use Semantic UI to style your component, you can make use of `error` prop of your `<Form.Field />` to raise an error if form is not valid.

To keep track of whether the form is valid, you may use your state. As an option you may set `disabled` property of `Submit` button equal to the state variable indicating whether the form is valid.

The very basic form validation (to match the pattern of one capital letter followed by lowercase letters) you may find in the following live-demo:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { Form, Input, Button } = semanticUIReact

const rootNode = document.getElementById('root')

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    submitAttempted: false,
    isValid: {
      contactName: false,
      contactPhone: false,
      contactMail: false
    }
  }
  
  validateInput = (name,value) => { 
    switch(name){
      case 'contactName' : {
        if(/^[A-Z][a-z]+$/.test(value)){
          return true
        } else return false
      }
      case 'contactPhone' : {
        if(/^\d+$/.test(value)){ 
          return true
        } else return false
      }
      case 'contactMail' : {
        if(/^\w+@\w+\.\w{1,4}$/i.test(value)){
          return true
        } else return false
      }
      default: return false
    }
  }    

  onChange = ({target:{name,value}}) => 
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      isValid: {
        ...this.state.isValid,
        [name]: this.validateInput(name, value)
      }
    })
  
  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      submitAttempted: true
    })
    Object.values(this.state.isValid).every(Boolean) &&
    console.log(this.state.contactName, this.state.contactPhone, this.state.contactMail)
  }

  render(){    
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
        <Form.Field
          name="contactName"
          className=""
          control={Input}
          label="Contact Name"
          placeholder="Contact Name"
          value={this.state.contactName || ''}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          required
          error={(
            (this.state.submitAttempted && !this.state.isValid.contactName) &&
            {
              content: 'Valid contact name should contain upper-case letters followed by lower-case letters',
              pointing: 'below'
            }
          )}
        />
        <Form.Field
          name="contactPhone"
          className=""
          control={Input}
          label="Contact Phone"
          placeholder="Contact Phone"
          value={this.state.contactPhone || ''}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          required
          error={(
            (this.state.submitAttempted && !this.state.isValid.contactPhone) && 
            {
              content: 'Valid phone, should contain numbers only',
              pointing: 'below'
            }
          )}
        />
        <Form.Field
          name="contactMail"
          className=""
          control={Input}
          label="Contact Mail"
          placeholder="example@hello.com"
          value={this.state.contactMail || ''}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          required
          error={(
            (this.state.submitAttempted && !this.state.isValid.contactMail) &&
            {
              content: 'Valid e-mail format should be fulfilled',
              pointing: 'below'
            }
          )}
        />
        <Button 
          type="submit"
          disabled={
            this.state.submitAttempted && 
            !Object.values(this.state.isValid).every(Boolean)
          }
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    )
  }

}

render (
  <App />,
  rootNode
)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css" /><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-react/0.88.2/semantic-ui-react.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: at this moment, `onChange` looks like this: `  onChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };` . can it be modified to take your changes too? I don't know how to do that

Comment: I have more fields but I also tried to comment all of them but one and it still not work. Now, it doesn't let me write anyhing in the input field. I copied the code here, maybe it's clearer if it's the all file: https://pastebin.com/inV3wGip

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you put a lot of effort in helping me even if it still doesn't work for my case

Comment: I don't know to do that because the application is too big and I need to get a lot of dependecies. Thanks for your help

Comment: maybe if you have time I can share you my screen in a google meeting for a live demo

Comment: I created a running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-ritchie-41qgr?file=/src/App.js , here it works fine because I've commented `handleSubmitCreate` the part that creates the company if the introduced data is correct. But when I run in my code it doesn't behave like this, it lets me click the submit button and the page reloads, like in the case it was correctly created. But it doesn't create it, it can be seen on network tab that the call fails with code 500

Comment: @SamuraiJack : that doesn't sound like validation problem (when commented out part replaced with `console.log()`-ing submitted values it works just fine). If your intention was to append form data to Redux store and redirect, you may want to troubleshoot that part. Can't help you much with that without seeing the rest of related code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own validation to check if any of the inputs are empty or not when submit button is clicked if any input is empty show an alert.

This is not an inbuilt functionality you need to add the code for validation and alert yourself.

Comment: Unless OP is using a plugin this is correct, don't we just love form validation in React 