# Form pattern validation with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-props, react-forms

I have been working on a react form and I need to restrict users to put special characters and allow only these ones: [A-Za-z].

I have tried the below code but I am still able to insert inside special characters such as: '♥', '>', '+', etc.

```
export default Component (props {
  ...
  return (
   <input 
    pattern={props.pattern}
   /> 
  )
}
```

And I am sending it as a prop to my form:

```
<Component 
pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
/>
```

Can you let me know what I am missing and point out what could be the issue? Many thanks.

Comment: You need an onChange event to validate the pattern using pattern.test function.

Comment: You may check out full-blown demos of form validation for [MaterialUI-styled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62962725/11299053) form and the one [based on SemanticUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62885267/11299053). Hopefully, either of those will give you a clue about how to approach your problem.

Comment: You may try `pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$"`

Answer (score 46):

The `pattern` attribute on `input` only works on `submit` in vanilla HTML forms.

If you're using `react-hook-form`, it should be in the ref, like this:

```
<input
    name="email"
    ref={register({
      required: "Required",
      pattern: {
        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
        message: "invalid email address"
      }
    })}
  />
```

please have a check on react-hook-form doc.

Comment: This only works on submit, but I need to restrict user to input special characters before.

Comment: I don't know how to use it best with react-hook-form, but converting the field to controlled component and use html5 validation api may work. Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-seterror-swr80 . The firstName field is restricted with the pattern.I will add this use case in cksform library.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using react-hook-form v7 then use this:

```
<input
    placeholder="Email"
    {...register('email', {
        required: 'Email is required',
        pattern: {
            value: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
            message: 'Please enter a valid email',
        },
    })}
    type="email"
    required
    className="input"
/>
{formState.errors.email?.message && (
     <FormError errorMessage={formState.errors.email?.message} />
)}
```

Comment: how to implement this on a React Native component please help

Comment: there is an error: Cannot find name 'FormError'

Comment: Thanks. This validation worked for me. I removed input type email because I just wanted to disable the default popup of chrome/firefox,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is name then you can just exclude those special characters, use the every function on pattern, basically check that each pattern is true otherwise throw an error message that you can override as you prefer

```
 <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    ref={register({
    required: "required",
    maxLength: {
    value: 15,
          message: "must be max 15 chars",
        },
        validate: (value) => {
          return (
            [/[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /[0-9]/].every((pattern) =>
              pattern.test(value)
            ) || "cannot special chars, only lower, upper, number"
          );
        },
      })}
    />
    {errors.email ? <div>{errors.email.message}</div> : null}
```

Or for example if your field is a password and you want that the user include at least a special character, then it would be like this:

```
<label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
    <input
      type="password"
      name="password"
      id="password"
      ref={register({
        required: "required",
        minLength: {
          value: 8,
          message: "must be 8 chars",
        },
        validate: (value) => {
          return (
            [/[a-z]/, /[A-Z]/, /[0-9]/, /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/].every((pattern) =>
              pattern.test(value)
            ) || "must include lower, upper, number, and special chars"
          );
        },
      })}
    />
    {errors.password ? <div>{errors.password.message}</div> : null}
  </div>
```

Answer (score -8):

https://regexr.com/

Details documentation RegExp pattern ,

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31910055)

Comment: Lining docs is useless