# React Hook Form pattern validation not triggering

Tags: html, reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-glade-v44v9t?file=/src/App.js

I've built a form that automatically computes the calories based on three inputs – protein, carbs, and fat. I want it to validate the inputs onBlur, but it's not working, the `formState.errors` object is always empty. I've tried setting `mode: onBlur` in `useForm` to no avail. I want to validate that the input is a positive integer.

I am not using `input type="number` for [many reasons](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/)

Answer (score 0):

Pattern param works only for vanilla validations. For library checks, you can use custom validation (`validate: input => input.match(/\d*/) == null || 'Error message'`) or use `ref` like in [Form pattern validation with react-hook-form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000638/form-pattern-validation-with-react-hook-form)

Small note - it's not really a good idea to use non-strings as a form value. It's always easier to use the same as a string and convert on processing. In this case, you will not have issues with missing methods (`number` doesn't have `match`). In your case, you can use `React.useEffect` to monitor changes and check validation errors before converting strings to numbers and multiplying them.

I hope it helps.

Comment: How would I use `useEffect` for the computation? Something like 
```js
useEffect(() => {
    const computedCalories =
      (parseInt(protein) || 0) * 4 +
      (parseInt(carbs) || 0) * 4 +
      (parseInt(fat) || 0) * 9;
    return computedCalories;
  }, [protein, carbs, fat]);
```

Comment: @MarcFletcher something like this: ```const [callories, setCallories] = React.useState(0);
React.useEffect(()=>{
 if(formErrors) return;

 setCallories(parseInt(protein) * 4 + parseInt(carbs) * 4 + parseInt(fat) * 9);
}, [protein, carbs, fat])```